# How to host the NextJs App served using Firebase Cloud Function on custom domain

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Previously the app was hosted on custom domain through firebase itself as it was a ReactApp but I have moved the app to nextjs and started using Server Side Rendering. I have hosted the app using firebase cloud functions and it works prefectly on the URL provided after deployment. But now on the custom domain that was connected previously it shows "Welcome to Firebase Hosting" you need to configure it.

This is my firebase.json file
[image]

This is my function.js file
[image]

And this is the package.json file
[image]

Edit: I found this in documentation

**Any connected custom domains:
CUSTOM_DOMAIN/bigben**

Can't I host it on root URL?

Comment: Here's the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions). It details all the steps you would need to connect hosting to your functions.

Comment: I am pretty sure i know the answer but i wont tell you because you didn't show any code or any thing.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @samthecodingman, there is an appropriate [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) that lists your requirement of hosting the Cloud Functions in Firebase Hosting using a custom domain.

Below are the steps for connecting Cloud Functions to Firebase Hosting :

1. Make sure that you have the latest version of the Firebase CLI and
   that you've initialized Firebase Hosting.
2. Initialize Cloud Functions by running the following command from the
   root of your project directory:
   `firebase init functions` 
   When prompted, select JavaScript (this walk-through example uses JS).
   Check that you have a functions directory in your local project
   directory.
3. Open /functions/index.js in your favorite editor. Replace the file's
   contents with the following code. This code creates an HTTPS
   function (named bigben) that replies to HTTPS requests with a BONG
   for each hour of the day, just like a clock.

[image]

4. Test your functions locally using the [Firebase Local Emulator Suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite).
   From the root of your local project directory, run the following command:

   `firebase emulators:start`
5. Access the function via the local URL returned by the CLI,
   http://localhost:5001/PROJECT_ID/us-central1/bigben.
6. The following steps show you how to direct all requests from the path ../bigben on your Hosting site to execute the bigben function.

   I. Open your firebase.json file.
   II. Add the following rewrite configuration under the hosting section:
   [image]

   III. Confirm that your redirect works as expected by testing again with the Firebase emulators.
7. Deploy your function and your Hosting content and config to your site by running the following command from the root of your local project directory:

   `firebase deploy --only functions,hosting`
8. Access your live site and your function at the following URLs:

   a. Your Firebase subdomains: 
   PROJECT_ID.web.app/bigben and PROJECT_ID.firebaseapp.com/bigben

   b. Any connected [custom domains](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain): 
   CUSTOM_DOMAIN/bigben
9. You can use web frameworks, like [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/), in Cloud Functions to serve your app's dynamic content and write complex web apps more easily. The client set up code example is also provided [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#use_a_web_framework).

Answer (score -1):

your `firebase.json` is missing `predeploy`. and you should also use `firebase-functions/v2`, as v1 doesn't work for next.js.

checkout my article: https://yihui.dev/firebase-hosting-with-nextjs-and-cloud-functions

and the github example: https://github.com/yihui-he/firebase-nextjs-example

Comment: yihui.dev, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)